# Mysql Stored procedure that accepts a date range from user and displays a list of open bugs

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, user-input

I am newbie to MySQL especially to writing stored procedures and functions. Faced lots of errors in writing code that accepts user input and date time manipulation. I have created table called 'BUGS' as below...

---

```
create table 'BUGS' (
    ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    TITLE varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    SEVERITY INT NOT NULL check(SEVERITY>0 && SEVIRITY<5),
    OPENDATE datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CLOSEDATE datetime default NULL
 )ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

I want to write below two things.

1. Block of code that accepts user input(here TITLE, SEVERITY, OPENDATE, CLOSEDATE) and insert one row.
2. Stored procedure that accepts a date range from user and displays a list of open bugs(for which opendate between the given date range and closedate beyond date range)

Can somebody help me with the code?

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Basically, you need a `INSERT INTO BUGS (values)` query, and a `SELECT * FROM BUGS WHERE DATE BETWEEN 01/01/2000 00:00:00 and 07/20/2016 00:00:00`

Comment: @Bonnati-I am newbie to MySQL and learning the things by referring to all possible resources on net and never written a stored procedure code before. I started to write the code for this today only which is my first practise session in MySQL but lots of errors in that and it would not be a good idea to paste the code here in the post and ask others to rectify the errors. Instead if one can provide a code for this example it will solve most difficulties(and as then only I will be able to compare the same with my code line by line and come to know the cause and rectification).

Comment: I understand the dificulties of starting a new tool, specially when it requires additional tools to work with. A database is not meant to "query itself", rather, is a repository of information. This tool allow other ones, such as PHP, Java, C, etc. to query it, and return a dataset that contains the "answer" to what was "asked". I higly suggesting adding details, such as what you are using (PHP / C / Java / Android / etc) to query your database, since they have different approaches. I suggest as well, understanding [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) concepts.

Comment: @Bonatti- I am aware that this can be done in combination with any front end language. But I more interested to do totally in MySQL stored procedure. And I m using MySQL prompt on command line and not any tool.

Comment: @Bonatti- I am sure this does not depend on CRUD concepts.

Comment: And what are the `SELECT` and `INSERT` queries you tried?

Comment: @Bonnati- I already know how to write select and insert queries. My problem with stored procedure code(1. here it should take from user input. This I tried but its not working. i.e. I am not sure about its syntax. and secondly how to accept dates from user. Now don't ask me that do I know programming logic as I have been doing this for many years. My problem is with sql code as I am not proficient in MySQL. I would have done it easily in Oracle but that is not what I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can write procedure like this :

1 . At first call procedure from your php file(if you have it) like this :

```
$report1=$db->query("call procedure_name('".$opendate."','".$closedate."')");
```

2 . Write this code in procedure file :

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE db_name.procedure_name(IN opendate varchar (15), IN closedate VARCHAR (15))
BEGIN
  //write here mysql query
END
```

Comment: @Paramjeet-writing the stored procedure code is my exact difficulty as I am a newbie to MySQL. I am still in learning phase.

Comment: So how can i help you ?

Comment: @Paramjeet- please read the comment that I have added to Bonnati.